# How to input rank in LSTM in keras

Tags: python, keras, classification, lstm

I have about 1000 nodes dataset where each node has 4 time-series. Each time series is exactly 6 length long. The **label** is 0 or 1. The **rank** is only availble if the label is `1`.

More precisely my dataset looks as follows.

```
node, time-series1, time_series2, time_series_3, time_series4, Label, rank
n1, [1.2, 2.5, 3.7, 4.2, 5.6, 8.8], [6.2, 5.5, 4.7, 3.2, 2.6, 1.8], …, 1, 8
n2, [5.2, 4.5, 3.7, 2.2, 1.6, 0.8], [8.2, 7.5, 6.7, 5.2, 4.6, 1.8], …, 0, N/A
and so on.
```

Initially, I forgot the `rank` column of my data and performed a binary classification using the following LSTM model.

```
input1 = Input(shape=(6,1))
x1 = LSTM(10)(input1)
input2 = Input(shape=(6,1))
x2 = LSTM(10)(input2)
input3 = Input(shape=(6,1))
x3 = LSTM(10)(input3)
input4 = Input(shape=(6,1))
x4 = LSTM(10)(input4)

x = concatenate([x1,x2,x3,x4])
output = Dense(40)(x)

model = Model(inputs=[input1,input2,input3,input4], outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(data1.shape) #(1000,6,1)
model.fit([data1,data2,data3,data4], target)
```

However, now I also want to incorporate the `rank` column into my model. I am new to LSTMs and this is my first ever keras application. Therefore, I am just wondering if it is possible to do this *using my existing model* or *using another model in keras*? I would also like to get other suggestions.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: Did you try adding a second output to the neural network, corresponding to the rank ? You need to map the unknown value of rank to some value, but it should be reasonable to do so. Is the rank categorical ? or a scalar ?

Comment: @PedroMarques Thank you very much for the comment. My ranks are like as follows: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, .... `. Ya, as you have suggested I can map N/A to `0` or something for the moment. Do you have any suggestions? :)

Comment: Mapping the rank to 0 would probably be ok. You can also map it to say -10 if you are using a MSE loss and don't want it to be confused with values "near to 1". My suggestion would be to add one or more hidden layers after you merge the LSTMs and before the outputs are split.

Comment: @PedroMarques Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Sure, I think it is a great idea to make `N/A` to `-10`. Sure, I will add another `Dense` layer in between `concetenation` and `output`. However, I am still not sure, where the rank column should come in the code? It would be really great if you could tell me how to do that as I am still new to LSTM layers. Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would structure the model like the following, as a starting point:

```
import tensorflow as tf

keras = tf.keras

inp = keras.layers.Input(shape=(6, 4))
rnn = keras.layers.LSTM(16)(inp)
h1 = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(rnn)
h2 = keras.layers.Dense(8)(h1)
out1 = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='label')(h2)
out2 = keras.layers.Dense(1, name='rank')(h2)

model = keras.models.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=[out1, out2])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss={'label': 'binary_crossentropy', 'rank': 'mse'},
              metrics={'label': 'accuracy'})
model.summary()
```

Note that in this example the input is shaped as (6, 4), i.e. 6 time steps with 4 measurements each. This assumes that the time series are somewhat related. As per your description the label is binary and rank seems to have dimension 1 also.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this in my dataset and will let you know. By the way it would be really great if you could show me how I can modify my existing code with your idea of adding the new layer. So, that I can also compare the performance. Thank you very much once gain for your great support. Looking forward to hearing from you :)